# Checking if subscription is cancelled in Google Wallet

Tags: subscription, android-pay

I'm looking to implement Google Wallet for digital goods' subscription on my website.

I understand how it works with postback on start and cancellation.

I'm worried if cancellation postback fail contacting my server. As I have a rather large amount of subscriptions, checking manually would be bothersome so I was wondering if there is any way to check subscription state contacting google wallet servers (like Paypal API).

How do you manage failed cancelation postback ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no API to "query" - it would be nice to have :) I recall asking a similar question back in one of Google's developer hangouts about "repurposing" some of the now deprecated Google Checkout API which did have "query apis".

I'd suggest you mitigate things by logging all notifications - aka "notification history". If you experience a processing error on your end, you'd still have access to the "raw data".

Of course this assumes 2 things, (1) Google will never fail sending you a postback, and (2) your server/s are always ready (if they're down, then they can't receive).

Unless I'm corrected by a Googler, I don't believe I've seen a "retry policy" -  error on either end - e.g. in GCO API postbacks were resent until the merchant successfully "acknowledges" receipt of the postback. Until then, I think you're down to looking at Merchant Center (manual).

Hth...

Comment: So this make subscription a no-go for my company. Not being able to know when they pay was already hard to manage for our accounting department but not knowing for sure if they ended their subscriptions is really a big deal breaker. I'm surprised that a company like google allow such thing to happen.

Comment: @Naouak - I wouldn't go that far/don't misunderstand the above. **You will get notifications** - _both_ success and/or failure. That is the normal process. The above is relevant for those times if/when things fail only - and IMHO should be how you'd likely design things when working with _any_ 3rd party.

Comment: When designing with third parties, you always have to imagine worst case scénario. I have royalties to give according to payment I receive and user usage. If I can't know for sure that an user is still paying, I would lose money and my accounting would be false. If anyone is aware of this problem, you only have to unsubscribe during a server failure(and that some times happen) and the server will never know that you stopped paying. I tried on the sandbox, there isn't any resend if the post back fail on unsubscribe.